# spring DMLC poller frequency change

Tags: spring, spring-jms, message-listener

Is it possible to change the poller frequency OOTB in DefaultMessageListenerContainer. If so, is it a dynamic configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

See the `receiveTimeout` property - the thread blocks for up to this time until a message arrives; yes it can be changed after the container starts - but it won't take effect until the thread is released by the client library.

It defaults to 5 seconds; if there's no message, the container immediately loops around and receives again.

Setting it to a too-high value will make the container less responsive to `stop()` invocations.

Comment: I am referring to a situation where the messages are coming in continuously. In this case, the receiveTimeout will not be useful I think. The idea is to reduce the rate at which DMLC consumes messages. Something like Thread.sleep between calls.

Comment: Then I don't know what you mean - the container is message-driven so messages will be delivered as they arrive, it is not polled in that sense - the container continually receives messages from the client library. If you want to "pull" messages on-demand, use the `JmsTemplate` `receive` methods instead.

Comment: The intention is to "control" the rate at which messages are being consumed. This makes a lot of relevance in those situation where for example you want to achieve a dynamic distribution of load  among various listeners(assume a listener belongs to a node in the cluster)

Comment: You can't do that with the standard container; you can subclass it and override `receiveMessage(Consumer consumer)` to add a delay.

Comment: cool. If you say this, at-least it is doable. Will try my hands at it. The idea will be to look at overall load in the system and keep on changing the receive call frequency dynamically.